# Change partitions' labels only on Dolphin or change label on not mounted LUKS partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, kde, kde-plasma-5

I have an encrypted LUKS partition, on Kubuntu such partition has to be displayed like **"831.5 GiB Encrypted Drive"** and cannot be changed. When you mount it and put the password it appears a new entry with the actual custom label.
What i hate about this is that "831.5 GiB Encrypted Drive" is too long and it's ugly on Dolphin. Can i change it somehow? On Dolphin only would be good enough.

Comment: Tried hiding the listing in Dolphin, maybe through right-clicking somewhere, or a preference? It kind-of works on Thunar, but hides the encrypted *and* decrypted device... not sure about Dolphin

Answer (score 1):

Technically Dolphin shows the "filesystem label" (stored in the filesystem's own metadata), not the partition label (stored in the partition table). LUKS1 cannot store a label in its metadata, although LUKS2 can.

If your encrypted volume is in LUKS2 format, you can rename it using:

```
cryptsetup config /dev/sdXY --label "Encrypted disk"
```

If you have an older format volume but cryptsetup 2.x is installed, you can quickly convert the volume header from LUKS1 to LUKS2 (this does not need to reencrypt the data):

```
cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sdXY --header-backup-file ~/sdXY-before-luks2-conversion.header
cryptsetup convert /dev/sdXY --to luks2
```

To check whether your system supports LUKS2 for data disks (i.e. non-boot/system), run `cryptsetup --version` to find out; you should see at least "2.0.2". (Note that GRUB2 supports *only* LUKS1 for the boot disk.)

To check the current header version, use `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdXY`.

Comment: Thank you for replaying. I don't know if it's LUKS 1 or 2, how do i check? It says only LUKS. That said: the terminal command you gave me doesn't work. It does nothing. I think you got it wrong: i can change the label of the partition itself from Gparted, but when it is not mounted the label is the default which i cannot (and i want to) change. I think mine is LUKS2 at this point?

Comment: You also said that Dolphin shows the filesystem label and not the partition label, which is not true, all my partitions show my custom partition label, except the unmounted encrypted partition.

Comment: How did you set these partition labels?

Comment: From Gparted, actually KDE Partition Manager. Right click on the partition, proprieties: label.

Comment: **That's not the partition label.** Parted does not support reading/writing partition labels from GPT (and they don't even exist in MBR); it writes this field into the filesystem using e2label or similar tools, and even outright shows "This filesystem does not support setting a label" in other cases. If it was the partition label, it would show up in `partx /dev/sda` and would not depend on LUKS vs something else.

Comment: Ok, got it. On Gparted is more clear and there's the choice to change **partition label**. So: is it possible to change the shown name on Dolphin or not?

Comment: No, even though the _menu item_ used to be titled "partition label" ([they changed it in 2014](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/commit/332a2e7a79048b06bedb707d40d98e5f44d3f5e0)), it still writes a filesystem label only. Recent GParted versions support both label kinds, and they have two menu options to make it clearer: "Name Partition" (change partlabel) and "Label File System" (change fs label). Unfortunately, Dolphin won't care about the partition label even if you set it.

Comment: As for changing the shown name in Dolphin, _see the main post._